# Open object in new window

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to open a SoundCloud player in a new window when a user clicks a link. Below is an example:

```
<object height="220" width="220"><param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/124173519&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed allowscriptaccess="always" width="220" height="220" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/124173519&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed></object>
```

I've tried various tricks, but to no avail. If a user could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try: `target="_blank"` as GuyT said. Wrap the object in a a element

Comment: can you share what you have tried? FYI this shows the html for an `object` element not an `a`

Answer (score 1):

Create something like: `<a href='javascript:window.open("page.html")' target="_blank" >link</a>` where you include the `<object ../>` tag in 'page.html'.

Answer (score 0):

if you can dynamically generate the object with a complete html, you can use javascript:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

Example of Server side script:

```
//playsound.php

<html>
<head>
  .....
</head>
<body>
 ......
<object height="220" width="220"><param name="movie" value="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/124173519&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed allowscriptaccess="always" width="220" height="220" src="https://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/124173519&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;player_type=artwork" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed></object>
</body>
</html>
```

So if a user clicks on the link in the main window, another window pops up to play the media. I hope this helps